# Using SliverPersistentHeader without that the Header is shrinking but just disappearing in Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-sliver, flutter-sliverappbar

I'm creating a Website and would want to have like a SliverAppBar oder a SliverPersistentHeader with an Image Carousel. That I can totally make, but I don't want the Image Carousel to shrink, when im scrolling down. Instead I would want the SliverAppBar to disappear but without the width getting smaller, but instead just the height getting smaller. I hope that my problem is clear. If there are any questions, please ask.
Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/Widgets/HomePageWidgets/ImageCarousel.dart';
import '../Widgets/GlobalWidgets/TopNavBar.dart';
//import 'package:flutter_app/Widgets/HomePageWidgets/HomePageImage.dart';
import '../Widgets/GlobalWidgets/BottomBar.dart';
import '../Widgets/HomePageWidgets/ImageCarousel.dart';
import '../Widgets/GlobalWidgets/OneCard.dart';
import '../Widgets/GlobalWidgets/TwoCards.dart';


class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Material(
      child: Container(
        child: CustomScrollView (
          slivers: [
            // HomePageImage(), //wurde durch ImageCarousel() ersetzt
            SliverAppBar(
              expandedHeight: screenSize.height * 0.9,
              backgroundColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(1),
              flexibleSpace: ImageCarousel(), // AUTOPLAY MUSS ANGESTELLT WERDEN,
              ),
            SliverList(delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
              //ImageCarousel(), // AUTOPLAY MUSS ANGESTELLT WERDEN
              Expanded(
                child: Container(

                  child: Row(
                    // Die Row mache ich nur hin, damit ich die Seite zentrieren kann. Wenn alles nach links soll, dann einfach Row entfernen
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      TopNavBar(),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ), //TopNavBar // TODO 1: DropDownButton muss noch erstellt werden // TODO 2: Funktionen zu den Buttons müssen hinzufügt werden
              OneCard(),
              Container(height: 1000,
                width: 500,),
              BottomBar(), // TODO 3: Funktionen zu den Buttons müssen hinzufügt werden
            ]))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my Image Carousel:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';

// https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider Link zum Package


class ImageCarousel extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ImageCarouselState createState() => _ImageCarouselState();
}

class _ImageCarouselState extends State<ImageCarousel> {

  List imgList = [
    'assets/images/Mathildedoppelt.jpeg',
    'assets/images/reveuse2.jpeg',

  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return CarouselSlider(
      options: CarouselOptions(
        height: screenSize.height * 0.9, //Ich kann hier einfach * 1.2 rechnen und dann füllt es den ganzen Bildschirm aus
        aspectRatio: 16/9,
        viewportFraction: 1,
        initialPage: 0,
        enableInfiniteScroll: true,
        reverse: false,
        autoPlay: false, // AUTOPLAY MUSS UNBEDINGT AN
        autoPlayInterval: Duration(seconds: 6),
        autoPlayAnimationDuration: Duration(seconds: 3),
        enlargeCenterPage: false,
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      ),
      items: imgList
          .map((item) => Container(
        child: Center(
            child: Image.network(
              item,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              height: height,
            )),
      ))
          .toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the code with the SliverPersistentHeader:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/Widgets/HomePageWidgets/ImageCarousel.dart';
import '../Widgets/GlobalWidgets/TopNavBar.dart';
//import 'package:flutter_app/Widgets/HomePageWidgets/HomePageImage.dart';
import '../Widgets/GlobalWidgets/BottomBar.dart';
import '../Widgets/HomePageWidgets/ImageCarousel.dart';
import '../Widgets/GlobalWidgets/OneCard.dart';
import '../Widgets/GlobalWidgets/TwoCards.dart';


class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Material(
      child: Container(
        child: CustomScrollView (
          slivers: [
            // HomePageImage(), //wurde durch ImageCarousel() ersetzt
            /*SliverAppBar(
              expandedHeight: screenSize.height * 0.9,
              backgroundColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(1),
              flexibleSpace: ImageCarousel(), // AUTOPLAY MUSS ANGESTELLT WERDEN,
              ),*/
            SliverPersistentHeader(
              delegate: MyDynamicHeader(),
            ),
            SliverList(delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
              //ImageCarousel(), // AUTOPLAY MUSS ANGESTELLT WERDEN
              Expanded(
                child: Container(

                  child: Row(
                    // Die Row mache ich nur hin, damit ich die Seite zentrieren kann. Wenn alles nach links soll, dann einfach Row entfernen
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      TopNavBar(),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ), //TopNavBar // TODO 1: DropDownButton muss noch erstellt werden // TODO 2: Funktionen zu den Buttons müssen hinzufügt werden
              OneCard(),
              SizedBox(height: 20,),
              TwoCards(),
              Container(height: 1000,
                width: 500,),
              BottomBar(), // TODO 3: Funktionen zu den Buttons müssen hinzufügt werden
            ]))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class MyDynamicHeader extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    return ImageCarousel();
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate _) => true;

  @override
  double get maxExtent => 650.0;

  @override
  double get minExtent => 0.0;
}
```

Comment: can you include `ImageCarousel`?

Comment: Now its included :)

Comment: ok, you like to have `SliverPersistentHeader`? But I can't find any implementation on your code like extending `SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate`.

Comment: I tried to implement a SliverPersistentHeader but the Image Carousel still shrunk in terms of width. How should I build my SliverPersistentHeader so that the Image Carousel shrinks in term of height but not in width?

Comment: The thing is happening in here. When i scroll up, our image get smaller based on `SliverPersistentHeader`, do you want to fill width with image? also if you check controlling image size totally depend on `aspectRatio` of  `CarouselSlider`.

Comment: I added the code with the SliverPersistentHeader. I basically want the same animation as on this Website: https://www.mariotestino.com You understand my issue?

Comment: I think that is not even using header, that is an extra layer on the stack.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235768/discussion-between-tom-and-yeasin-sheikh).

Answer (score 0):

There is one thing is missing on swap, it will only show full image on swap like while swap it 2image show in screen. But animate functionality is not working for `carousel_slider.`
Though, hope it will provide you an idea. In this case, I may go for auto scrollList and use the controller.

**Demo Code:**

```
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomSS extends StatefulWidget {
  CustomSS({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CustomSSState createState() => _CustomSSState();
}

class _CustomSSState extends State<CustomSS> {
  final CarouselController controller = CarouselController();

  final imageList = [
    'assets/me.jpg',
    'assets/ocean.jpg',
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) => Stack(
          children: [
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              child: _ImageCarouselState(
                controller: controller,
                imgList: imageList,
                size: Size(
                  constraints.maxWidth,
                  constraints.maxHeight * .4,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              child: SizedBox(
                height: constraints.maxHeight,
                width: constraints.maxWidth,
                child: CustomScrollView(
                  slivers: [
                    SliverList(
                      delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                        [
                          ///ToolBar
                          SizedBox(
                            height: constraints.maxHeight * .4 + kToolbarHeight,
                            child: GestureDetector(
                              onHorizontalDragEnd: (details) {
                                if (details.primaryVelocity! > 0) {
                                  controller.previousPage();
                                }

                                // Swiping in left direction.
                                else if (details.primaryVelocity! < 0.0) {
                                  controller.nextPage();
                                }
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                          Column(
                            children: List.generate(
                              122,
                              (index) => Container(
                                height: 100,
                                width: constraints.maxWidth,
                                color:
                                    index.isEven ? Colors.red : Colors.yellow,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _ImageCarouselState extends StatelessWidget {
  final Size size;
  final List imgList;
  final CarouselController controller;
  _ImageCarouselState({
    Key? key,
    required this.size,
    required this.controller,
    required this.imgList,
  }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(
    BuildContext context,
  ) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        CarouselSlider(
          carouselController: controller,
          options: CarouselOptions(
            height: size.height,
            // height: screenSize.height *
            //     0.9, //Ich kann hier einfach * 1.2 rechnen und dann füllt es den ganzen Bildschirm aus
            aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
            viewportFraction: 1,
            initialPage: 0,
            enableInfiniteScroll: true,
            reverse: false,
            // autoPlay: true, // AUTOPLAY MUSS UNBEDINGT AN
            // autoPlayInterval: Duration(seconds: 1),
            // autoPlayAnimationDuration: Duration(seconds: 1),
            enlargeCenterPage: false,
            // scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          ),
          items: imgList
              .map((item) => Container(
                    width: size.width,
                    child: Center(
                        child: Image.network(
                      item,
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    )),
                  ))
              .toList(),
        ),
        Container(
          height: kToolbarHeight,
          color: Colors.cyanAccent,
          width: size.width,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Text(
                "TabBar",
              ),
              Text(
                "Or others",
              ),
              Text(
                "Items",
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```